# Is there a formula to find the position average for an exercise with athlete who play multiple sports

Tags: javascript, function, google-sheets, indexing, match

What formula should I use to find the average of an exercise based on people who play the same position? But it needs to be through more than 1 column due to athletes playing more than one sport.

Example of how data sheet headers is set up

Athlete | sport 1 | sport 2| position1| position2

Here is the formula I currently using.

=averageifs(index(data sheet,,match(exercise type,Headers,)),index(data sheet,,match("position 1",headers,)),athlete name)

•Data sheet contains all of numbers for exercises

•Headers is the first row of data sheet

The current formula I am using only takes the column with the header "position 1", but I am wanting to get positions 1-10 so I can get a more accurate position average for athletes who play multiple sports.
[data sheet w/ ‘headers’](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48rtP.jpg)

[formula used to get the position average](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kd706.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You'll need to also share more of your code

Comment: Does that help add more info about the code @JoshuaTerrill ?